# JqGrid add button to advanced search dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'd like to add the ability to save a complex query built up in the advanced search dialog.

Saving the generated SQL is no problem, but I'm not sure how to add buttons to the advanced search query dialog to give users the options of saving / loading a query.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly using the jqGrid API. However, you could use one of the optional events such as [afterShowSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options) to define a function that will dynamically add such buttons.

I suggest using FireBug to help reverse-engineer exactly where to place the buttons.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that. It was exactly what I was looking for.